# In Mongodb how can I view an index's values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I not asking how to view the indexes on a collection but how can I look inside the index and see its values?

I have a field that should be unique so I created a unique index and now I want to cross verify that all the documents are present in the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you cannot look inside the index. It's just linked list. But... You can do `count` from index. `db.data.find({},{"_id":1}).hint({"_id":1}).itcount()`

In that example I [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#behavior) only field `_id`, with [hint()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/index.html) I ordered system use unique index of "_id" and with itcount() I ordered NOT to use metadata information of count, but go thru that find cursor and do count of every item.